# nil и пустая строка в golang

Tags: golang

Пишу функцию с возвратом val, err
и если делать `return nil, err`, то выдаёт ошибку несоответствия типов 
***cannot use nil as type string in return argument***
, собственно я смотрел другой код и там делали так и всё работает, может есть конечно какие-то нюансы, я го недавно начал изучать, после Node и тщетной попытки разобраться с Rust, как в go правильно бросать ошибку?
Вот пример

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "gopkg.in/ldap.v2"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    data, err := Example()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(data)
}

func Example() (string, error) {
    _, err := ldap.Dial("tcp", "10.0.0.41:389")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return "OK", nil
}
```

PS:Дополню вопрос, понятно что есть несоответсвие типа данных, но я например смотрел исходники go-ldap - https://github.com/go-ldap/ldap/blob/master/search.go , там на строке 368 идёт обработка ошибки и вместо структуры возвращается nil, то есть получается иногда можно возвращать значение не того типа который ожидается?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Строка не может быть `nil`. Возвращайте пустую строку:

```
return "", err
```

Comment: Но вот например в коде котороый я смотрел возвращалась структура, и в обработчиках ошибко было return nil, err

Comment: @vnn198: Может, там не возвращалась строка?

Comment: @vnn198, там или указатель на структуру, или интерфейс возвращался.

Comment: А где можно почитать что может быть возвращено как nil, а что должно быть того-же типа?

Comment: @vnn198 https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь понятно, для структур и указателей nil допустим.

Comment: @vnn198 Для указателей - да. У структур свои нулевые значения, но как правило из функций возвращаются указатели на структуры, так что с ними встречаются реже.

Comment: Понятно, тема указателей для меня пока ещё покрыта небольшим мраком :)